# What is the alternative in HarmonyOS for activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content) in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a helper class to zoom an image in HarmonyOS using Java SDK. To get the current view which is being zoomed in Android we can use `activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

What is the alternative for the above in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in Android we can use activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).
> What is the alternative for the above in HarmonyOS?

In HarmonyOS we use `findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_xxx)`. Just Try this.